# store the option of a selectlist added by jquery into database using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I found a jquery snippet to add and remove options from a select box from box 1 to box 2. This works great. However, when i try to print_r in PHP of the box where the new options are added then it won't show. I cant even see it on the resource after submit. Any solution?

```
$('#btn-add').click(function(){
    $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
$('#btn-remove').click(function(){
    $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
        $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

});

and html of the two select lists

```
            <select class="gen" name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="6" style="width: 150px;">

        </select>
        <input name="" id="btn-add" type="button" class="add_list" style="vertical-align: top;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="" id="btn-remove" type="button" class="remove_list" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <select class="gen" name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="6" style="width: 150px;">
        </select>
```

upon submit i check the $_POST['selectto'] from the selectto box. Any idea's?

EDIT: the foreach in php;

```
                                $articles_ary = array();
                            foreach ($_POST['selectto[]'] as $options)
                            {
                                if (!empty($options))
                                {
                                    $articles_ary[] = $options;
                                }
                            }

                            print_r($articles_ary);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you `POST` a select the form submits only the selected option and bare in mind that it must be selected.
with your code you are just adding the options to the `selectto`, but you're not:

- a) chosing one of them (if you want a single value posted)
- b) chosing all of them to be posted on the PHP page. (if you want multiple values posted)

in the second case (i thought it's the one you need) you can use this simple jQuery function:

```
$("#buttonusedtosendform").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#select-to option').each( function() {
      $(this).attr('selected', true);  //with this you select all the option
    });
    $('formname').submit();
});
```

bare in mind that if you want to retrieve all the options of a select with `PHP` you will have to use a little trick by naming the select with square bracket at the end (it's a feature that PHP offer, where it will overwrite the former variable with the latest parsing each one separately):
eg. `selectto => selectto[]`
this way php will handle it as an array and let you retrieve all the value as if it is one:

```
foreach($_POST['selectto[]'] as $options){}
```

Comment: btw, i added the foreach on top and i get an empty array

Comment: hey, nvm that. I found the solution. the [] need to be in the name attribute on the selectbox and not in the POST['selectto']. Thanks for the help, i would never guessed this without you!

Answer (score 0):

When you enter data from one select box to second selectbox, you need to have items selected in second select box to show when you do print_r in php.

For this, after items are added to second select box say with id selectbox2, then you could select all items of second selectbox and then submit the form

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectbox2.options.length; i++) {
        selectbox2.options[i].selected = true;
}
//then Submit form like this, assuming your form name is form1
document.form1.submit();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, but as i'm not really used to jquery i didn't tought of that. So i still need to figure this out

Comment: I have edited the post please see the javascript code to select all items in second selectbox and submit the form.